# What structure do you get if you adjoint a root of $z \bar{z} = -1$ to the complex numbers?

Tags: soft-question, gm.general-mathematics

A pop-up is informing me that my question is likely to be closed.

Still, recall that the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ was conceived by trying to adjoint a root of the equation $x^2 = - 1$ to the field of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, or so we are told. There are two such roots, now known as $i$ and $-i$, and the conjugation involution $z \mapsto \bar{z}$ is the field automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ which fixes $\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose we entertain the fantasy to adjointing a root of the analogous equation $z \bar{z} = |z|^2 = -1$ to the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$. What "structure" will we get? Now, given such a root, call it $f$ for the fantasy unit, then $z= e^{i\theta}\cdot f $ would also be a root of $z \bar{z} = 1$ for all $e^{i\theta}$ in the circle group $U(1)$.

Comment: It looks like you are identifying $\mathbb{C}$ with the group of diagonal matrices $$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  z & 0 \\
  0 & z  \\
  \end{array}
\right)$$
and then you are adjointing the Pauli matrix $$J:=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  0 & -i \\
  i &  0\\
  \end{array}
\right).$$

Comment: In fact, we have $$J \bar{J}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
   0 & -i \\
  i & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right)  \left( \begin{array}{cc}
  0 & i \\
  -i & 0 \\
  \end{array}
\right) = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
  -1 & 0 \\
  \; \; 0 & -1 \\
  \end{array}
\right),$$
so  $J$ is actually a root of $J \bar{J}=-1$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the terminology of a Pauli matrix. Reading the Wikipedia description, it seems that $SU(2)$ and the quaternions come into play.

Comment: "... the complex numbers $\mathbf C$ were conceived by trying to adjoin a root of the equation $x^2=−1$ to the field of real numbers, or so we are told." Who told you that? The complex numbers were conceived because of the cubic formula for *real* solutions of cubic polynomials.  When a cubic has all three roots in $\mathbf R$, the cubic formula has square roots of negative numbers. Nobody was inventing new number systems to solve problems nobody cared about (like being able to solve $x^2 = -1$), but rather to do something of interest: find a formula for *real* solutions of a real cubic.

Comment: *casus irreducibilis* :-)

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate of my question ["Making extensions $L/K$ aware of the Galois group coming from $K/k$"](http://mathoverflow.net/q/248241/41291) but that one in turn was a followup of my math.SE question [Adding a root of $z\bar z=-1$ to $\mathbb C$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1902190/214353) with practically identical title :D Not that I have anything against, on the contrary, I am glad to see I was not alone in thinking about it

Comment: Thank you KConrad for the correction regarding the conception of the complex numbers due to solving real cubic polynomials.

Comment: Actually I would really like to accept Francesco's answer, where a complex number is regarded as a $2\times 2$ diagonal matrix. This construction has an exact analogue in the construction of the complex numbers from the real numbers.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to realize is that the question must be properly interpreted, which probably can be done in several ways.

It seems reasonable to interpret it as follows:

> Find a ring $R$ with an injective homomorphism $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow R$, such that:
>
> - there is an involution $\sigma: R \rightarrow R$, i.e. an endomorphism of order $2$, such that the restriction of $\sigma$ to $\mathbb{C}$ is the complex conjugation;
> - there is an element $f \in R$, such that $f \sigma(f) = -1$;
> - $R$ is generated by $\mathbb{C}$ and $f$.

The last condition can possibly be replace by: $R$ is generated by $\mathbb{C}$, $f$ and $\sigma(f)$.

But you probably also want to put other conditions on $R$.

For example, if you require $R$ to be commutative, then $R$ can be the ring $\mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}$, with $\mathbb{C}$ embedded diagonally, $\sigma(z, w)=(\overline{w}, \overline{z})$, and the element $f=(1, -1)$.

If you don't require $R$ to be commutative, then it can also be the biquaternion $R = \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C} i \oplus \mathbb{C} j \oplus \mathbb{C} k$.

For the moment I don't have an example where $R$ is still a division algebra and $f$ is algebraic.

Comment: We can just take the quaternions with involution $i \mapsto -i, \ j \mapsto j, \ k \mapsto -k$. Then $j$ is such a solution and $\mathbb C$ is a subfield.

Comment: For $R$ commutative, there is a simple universal solution to this problem: It is the ring au laurent polynomial $\mathbb{C}[Z,Z^{-1}]$ with the involution $P \mapsto \overline{P}(-1/Z)$. So as I understand the question, this is what we get when one freely add such $z$.

Comment: @SimonHenry I agree completely, that was exactly my suggestion in http://mathoverflow.net/q/248241/41291 and I am still thinking on it.

Comment: @SimonHenry Yes, I was aware of this example, which is why I added "$f$ algebraic" in the end (which doesn't quite make sense, though).

Comment: There is an interesting point here - although of course $Z$ in $\mathbb C[Z,Z^{-1}]$ is transcendental over the field $\mathbb C$, it is (by definition) algebraic over the ring-with-an-involution $(\mathbb C,\bar{\phantom z})$, once one extends complex conjugation to it via $\bar Z:=-1/Z$; my version in fact was to take $\mathbb C(Z)$, then algebraicity would hold in the signature of fields-with-an-involution.